# Deny Access (instead of 404) for non-existant user accounts

Tags: routes, users

For a particular project I'm working on, I'd like to return access denied instead of a 404 for non-existant user accounts. I've tried setting a custom 404 page callback and access callback in hook_menu(), and then returning FALSE when paths like `user/` are visited, but that doesn't help. I've also tried calling `drupal_access_denied()` directly in the callback, but that just results in a server error.

I've also tried overriding the `user/%user` menu item in hook_menu_alter(), but that has no effect on 404 not found pages.

Is there any way to get paths like `user/239841239` (any non-existent user ID) to show an access denied page instead of a 404?

[**Update**: I simply moved the code I was using in the custom 404 page access callback (see below) to the page callback, and now the access denied page is being served correctly.]

```
// If visiting a non-existent user page, redirect to access denied.
if (strpos(request_path(), 'user/') !== FALSE) {
  drupal_access_denied();
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: Nice: my karma is partying like it's 1999.

Comment: @Clive - well, now it's A Space Odyssey. And probably next time I notice, it'll be meaningless.

Comment: Sorry I did up-vote in the end, now it's just the year that [insert random fact from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006 here] happened ;)

Comment: re your server error, in a menu callback, you should `return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;` (or `return MENU_NOT_FOUND;`) instead of calling `drupal_access_denied()` etc

Comment: @Jimajamma - I tried that, too, and was getting an infinite loop for some reason, probably because something is different about the 404 handler + a custom page callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try setting up a conditional redirect from your 404 page to your custom users-specific error page, that only fires if the path of the referrer is user/*.

I would try to do this using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest thing... I moved the code from the 404 page's access callback to page callback, followed by a `drupal_exit()`, and it works. I'll update the question with the code I used (I'd rather not use Rules on this particular site).